# Enabling Google Cloud Logging

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-platform

From the Google Docs: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/install/compute_install#enable_the_google_cloud_logging_api

> You must enable the Google Cloud Logging API for your project:
>
> Navigate to the Developers Console UI and select your project
>
> Select APIs & auth > APIs in the sidebar on the left.
>
> Type "logging" in the search box under Browse APIs
>
> Toggle the status button from OFF to ON to enable the Google Cloud
>   Logging API.

When I go to my API console I don't see any option related to Google Cloud Logging API. If I try to write to my logs from a GCE instance `gcloud preview logging write test hello`, I get a 403 error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.preview.logging.write) ResponseError: status=403, code=Forbidden, message=Project has not enabled the API. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project.
```

This instance does have write permission for Cloud Logging.

How am I supposed to enable the Cloud Logging API?

Comment: "Google Cloud Monitoring API" should be enabled

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud Logging API is still an Alpha release and your project must be white listed before using it first. See the [header at the documentation page](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/install/compute_install):

**Alpha**
This is an Alpha release of Google Cloud Logging for Google Compute Engine. This API might be changed in backward-incompatible ways and is not recommended for production use. It is not subject to any SLA or deprecation policy. [Request to be whitelisted to use this feature.](https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/forms/d/11o2FbzKEgRM9sNuF4-dmIyML_5SPac9vIy4sMEU3S7k/viewform)

Comment: The Cloud Logging API is now in Beta release (as of March 19, see the [blog post](http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.com/2015/03/leverage-the-power-of-log-data-to-drive-operational-and-business-decisions-through-Google-Cloud-Logging.html)). Whitelisting is no longer required to use the API.